# How to fix "couldn't find module: ti.cloudpush for architecture: armv7" (Appcelerator Titanium)

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I've just upgraded Appcelerator Studio and updated my project from Titanium SDK v5.0.2.GA to 5.3.0.GA, it works fine on Android (although I had to remove a color property from the ProgressBar so it rendered correctly), but on iOS it showed a red error screen with the following message...

> Couldn't find module: ti.cloudpush for architecture: armv7

The Console reports the following...

> [INFO] :   App started [ERROR] :  Script Error Couldn't find module:
> ti.cloudpush for architecture: armv7
>
> [ERROR] :  Script Error Module
> "ui/common/LoginWindow" failed to leave a valid exports object
>
> [ERROR] :  Script Error Module "common/Services" failed to leave a valid
> exports object
>
> [ERROR] :  ErrorController is up. ABORTING showing of modal controller
>
> [ERROR] :  ErrorController is up. ABORTING showing of
> modal controller

A quick google search implied that I needed to change some manifest files and recompile the module - but it's not a module I wrote, it's provided by Appcelerator (Titanium).

Could someone please guide me to what's required to fix this problem?

Reverting to 5.0.2.GA - also blows up, so perhaps something in the Appcelerator Studio has broken something, or Applie/XCode has some new requirements?

I'm deploying via USB - no AppStore at this stage.

My project has the following (note many of the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities are commented out, no changes here for many months)...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ti:app xmlns:ti="http://ti.appcelerator.org">
    <id>com.devology.****.app</id>
    <name>****</name>
    <version>1.37</version>
    <publisher>*****</publisher>
    <url>https://www.****.com</url>
    <description>****</description>
    <copyright>****</copyright>
    <icon>appicon.png</icon>
    <!-- Android = appicon.png -->
    <!--    <fullscreen>false</fullscreen><navbar-hidden>false</navbar-hidden>
   -->
    <analytics>true</analytics>
    <guid>****</guid>
    <property name="ti.ui.defaultunit" type="string">dp</property>
    <ios>
        <min-ios-ver>6.0</min-ios-ver>
        <!-- 6.0 would exclude iPad 1-->
        <!-- 7.0 is minimum version for armv7s-->
        <plist>
            <dict>
                <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
                <string>****</string>
                <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
                <string>****</string>
                <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~iphone</key>
                <array>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
                </array>
                <!--
                <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key><array><string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string><string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string><string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string><string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string></array>
                -->
                <key>UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key>
                <!-- specifies whether the app requires a Wi-Fi connection. iOS maintains the active Wi-Fi connection open while the app is running. -->
                <false/>
                <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
                <false/>
                <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
                <true/>
                <key>beta-reports-active</key>
                <true/>
                <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
                <string>UIStatusBarStyleDefault</string>
                <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>location</string>
                    <!--
                        Causes rejection by Apple, but shouldn't need backgrounded sound
                        because we use notifications to do this
                        <string>audio</string>
                    -->
                </array>
                <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
                <array>
                    <!--<string>armv7</string>-->
                    <!--iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4, iPhone 4S, iPod 3G/4G/5G, iPad, iPad 2, iPad 3, iPad Mini -->
                    <!--<string>armv7s</string>-->
                    <!-- iPhone 5, iPad 4 -->
                    <string>gps</string>
                    <!-- You should require GPS only if your app needs location data more accurate than the cellular or Wi-fi radios might otherwise provide. -->
                    <string>location-services</string>
                    <!-- if you include 'gps' key, you should also include the location-services key -->
                    <!--<string>sms</string> -->
                    <!-- Include this key if your app requires (or specifically prohibits) the presence of the Messages app. You might require this feature if your app opens URLs with the sms scheme. -->
                    <!--<string>telephony</string> -->
                    <!-- Include this key if your app requires (or specifically prohibits) the presence of the Phone app. You might require this feature if your app opens URLs with the tel scheme. -->
                    <!--<string>wifi</string>-->
                    <!-- Include this key if your app requires (or specifically prohibits) access to the networking features of the device. -->
                </array>
            </dict>
        </plist>
    </ios>
    <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <manifest android:versionCode="37" android:versionName="1.37">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SOUND"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
        </manifest>
        <services>
            <service type="interval" url="common/androidBackgroundService.js"/>
        </services>
    </android>
    <mobileweb>
        <precache/>
        <splash>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <inline-css-images>true</inline-css-images>
        </splash>
        <theme>default</theme>
    </mobileweb>
    <modules>
        <module platform="android">ti.cloudpush</module>
        <module platform="commonjs">ti.cloud</module>
    </modules>
    <deployment-targets>
        <target device="blackberry">false</target>
        <target device="android">true</target>
        <target device="ipad">false</target>
        <target device="iphone">true</target>
        <target device="mobileweb">false</target>
    </deployment-targets>
    <sdk-version>5.0.2.GA</sdk-version>
....
</ti:app>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned that "but on iOS it showed a red error screen with the following message...",.....

The ti.cloudpush module is only for Android as you can also see it from these lines in tiapp.xml:

```
<modules>
    <module platform="android">ti.cloudpush</module>
    <module platform="commonjs">ti.cloud</module>
</modules>
```

Now, the problem could be that you have not put a check on OS wherever you are requiring the cloudpush module.

I suggest you to look into that code where you are calling it by something like this :

```
var CloudPush = require('ti.cloudpush');
```

So, to make it work, use this code:

```
var CloudPush;

if (OS_ANDROID) {
   CloudPush = require('ti.cloudpush');
}
```

If it does not help, then share some code where you are calling this module.

Comment: Thanks @Prashant-Saini - I hate it when I do something stupid, unfortunately I started the Android changes over 6 weeks ago, resumed recently and forgot I hadn't run it on iOS since adding CloudPush.  I had carefully put if conditions around everything other than the require block.  Thank you!!   It goes to show when you do an upgrade of Appcelerator Titanium and the SDK it's too easy to think they broke something ;-)